# Intellij IDEA. Always show maven's `target` directory

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When creating maven project using Intellij IDEA, by default `target` directory is not visible in Project explorer. But I can make it visible by removing it from excluded folders in module settings. But it work only for short period of time, and after 10-15 minutes `target` directory again invisible. So I need again go to module settings and remove `target` directory from Excluded directories.

How I can make visible maven's `target` directory forever?

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ?

Comment: I suggest you ask Jetbrains directly.  They usually respond to my questions quickly.

Comment: Update to V14 and there is an option for this in the project pane, if i am not mistaken

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try to uncheck the **Exclude build directory** checkbox under `Settings - Project Settings - Maven - Importing`.

Description from IDEA help:

> Select this check box to exclude a build directory from the project. This might be useful, if you want to speed up the project's importing process . If this check box is cleared, IntelliJ IDEA will index files in the build directory every time you import a project which might take additional time.

Comment: when you complete the setup, run the clean install task , the target folder is visible now

Answer (score 37):

In IDEA version 14 or higher you can try to uncheck "show excluded files" in the project panel set. It is checked by default. I found this solution [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-129233#comment=27-791816).

Comment: Also a very important comment there **Switch to "Project" scope instead of "Project Files"**.

Comment: I know, your answer is quite old but: For me, this does not work with the maven "target" directory, for some reason (Idea 2017.3.1 Ultimate)

Comment: Nice, but there are some additional tips: 1) The options is shown by click the setting icon on top right of the project panel. 2) Even after uncheck the IDEA's own files are still shown, (e.g `.idea/` dir, `.iml` file).

Answer (score 5):

This can be directly configured in File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> {select your module} -> Sources

There you will see which folders are excluded from being shown in Project explorer.
Just remove the "target" from the exclusion list and it will be shown from that moment on.

Comment: Downvoted, because the target folder should be excluded; anyhow the question was how to show it in project view even it is excluded.