# IntelliJ fails to sync changes in the target folder

Tags: java, linux, maven, intellij-idea, target

Intellij 12.0.4 (build 123.169) on Linux Mint 13.

When I run maven tests from command line, I can see the changed contents of the `target` folder in the file explorer, but not in IntelliJ.

I have tried the `Synchronize` option from the context menu as well as the Ctrl+Alt+Y shortcut on different levels - subfolder, folder and module. I also cannot open the files using the Ctrl+Shift+N open/search.

The idea.log looks unsuspicious:

```
2013-04-01 08:51:07,808 [3911692]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 26 ms 
2013-04-01 08:51:07,808 [3911692]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 0 files to update 
2013-04-01 08:51:07,808 [3911692]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update done in 0 ms
```

Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273153/intellij-idea-always-show-mavens-target-directory). It's issue was that the `target` folder was not visible at all.

I had to go to Settings -> Project Settings -> Maven -> Importing. Then uncheck `Exclude build directory`, reimport the module and it worked.

Still strange that in my case the folder was visible but not updateable.