# intallij-idea: What is the purpose of "Exclude output paths"?

Tags: intellij-idea

I wonder what is the purpose of "Exclude output paths" option in module settings.
I didn't notice any differencr in ide behaviour by setting it or not.
Official manual does not help:
"Exclude output paths. Select this check box to make the output directories excluded."
But excluded from WHAT? (great help: "set this option to make it set" :)

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option excludes paths like `/target` or `/bin` - where the build results are -  from being displayed in the project view and the files in these paths cannot be selected over shortcuts like `Ctrl+Shift+N`.

Comment: Hi; but I don't have any output paths nor files visible in project view; is it a question of another setting? I can see only src and and .idea directories

Comment: @ardabro If you have not excluded the paths, have them on your filesystem and still dont see them in the project view, something might be wrong with the IntelliJ version. I had a case with IntelliJ 12 where I excluded the paths but they were partially  visible in the project view, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739261/intellij-fails-to-sync-changes-in-the-target-folder