# Intellij Open File Resource ( Ignore target folder )

Tags: intellij-idea

When I use the command + shift + o command I get this popup:

[image]

The problem is that in a Java EE applicaton there will be **duplicates in the target** folder. Sometimes I start editing the wrong file. I do not want them listed, see picture. Is there a way to exclude folders?

**Also, on another note:**

Sometimes intellij will highlight as error a method call, thinking it matches some other class. Not possible to ignore error ( doesn't help ), and no way of pointing the right method or class manually. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Make sure that the `target` folder is excluded in the `Project Structure | Modules`:

[image]

---

It should have been excluded automatically since it is a maven project (I assume).

Comment: Actually, this works, but is buggy. It seems to be ignored after a while and I have to repeat this step.

Comment: @mojs It never fails for me and I have never had to follow my own advice to manually exclude the target folder. I hope you are not using `mvn idea:idea`.

Comment: @MoJS I have done this myself. mvn clean deletes a directory that IntelliJ is tracking as an ignored directory, IntelliJ seems unable to remember that it was ignoring that directory.

Comment: Ha! It was a I said, I knew I was not a fool! hahah

Comment: @MoJS I added an answer (another post) I found that I think can do what you want permanently :) Give it a try and let me know if it works. I'm using it myself, now.

Comment: @maba please not that this doesnt work all that well

Comment: Is there some setting to make it globally? I do not have a standard maven directory structure and do not want to manually do this for all my ~20 modules. I need to exclude `target` and `dist` folders`.

Answer (score 1):

I have done what @maba recommended myself but it comes back whenever mvn clean deletes a directory that IntelliJ is tracking as an ignored directory, IntelliJ seems unable to remember that it was ignoring that directory. Perhaps it sticks a configuration file in the target directory it's trying to ignore? In any case, this answer worked for me even after I ran a mvn clean.

[Intellij IDEA. Always show maven's `target` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273153/intellij-idea-always-show-mavens-target-directory)

Comment: Won't this always show the target directory, while maba wants to always hide the target directory?

Comment: @DaveCameron It's been a while since I looked at this question, but I think my point was that you could click on the button to enable the Exclusion of the build directory.