# How IntelliJ IDEA automatically detects and ignore target directory from a Git repo without even using .gitignore file?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA for the first time. I added my already existing project to the Git and when I saw the **Unversioned** and **Ignored** files, I saw the `target/` directory is already in the **Ignore Field** list. Since I don't even have the `.gitignore` file yet, how the `target/` directory is being excluded from Git?

**Update**: Yes it's a Maven project

1. `Preferences | Editor | File Types, Ignore files and folders`: ***.hprof;*.pyc;*.pyo;*.rbc;*.yarb;*~;.DS_Store;.git;.hg;.svn;CVS;__pycache__;_svn;vssver.scc;vssver2.scc;**
2. `.git/info/exclude`:

   **# git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude

   # Lines that start with '#' are comments.

   # For a project mostly in C, the following would be a good set of

   # exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):

   # *.[oa]

   \ # *~**
3. `git config --global core.excludesfile` point me to 'some-path/some-path/.gitignore_global' and the content inside is:
   ***~

   .DS_Store**

Comment: It may automatically write some ignore patterns to `.git/info/exclude` according to the type of your project.

Comment: Is it a Maven project? There is "Exclude Build directory" option in "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing"

Comment: @ElpieKay Please see the update.

Comment: @y.bedrov but I guess that's the setting applied while importing the Maven project.

Comment: @TheCoder Try `git check-ignore -v <ignored_filepath>`.

Comment: @ElpieKay response : `.gitignore:4:*.class`

Comment: @TheCoder So it's defined in `.gitignore`.

Comment: @ElpieKay Sorry, I accidentally checked it on the updated project where `.gitignore` exist. So now I tried after deleting the `.gitignore` and it returned **nothing**. Also, the ignored files are still the same.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000721750-Excluding-directories-globally)

`Preferences | Editor | File Types, Ignore files and folders` allows to ignore files/folders globally.

Check also your `git config --global core.excludesfile` settings, which can be updated.
And, as commented, your project `.git/info/exclude` file.

Note that the default JetBrains `.gitignore` does not ignore `.idea/workspace.xml` files in nested folders, for instance. (See [issue IDEA-90785](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-90785))

[image: settings]

> `workspace.xml` is used to store user-specific (non-shared) run configurations.

Comment: Is is excluded in the project module? (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16832757/6309 and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#excluded_root)

Comment: Isn't `workspace.xml` responsible for this ignorance of target directory, see my answer.

Comment: @TheCoder That is possible indeed.

Answer (score 0):

So I was digging some IDEA blogs and then I found [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems). There is a `workspace.xml` file created by the IDEA which contains the ignored path, This is an entry there
 `<ignored path="$PROJECT_DIR$/my-website-REST/target/" />`
I believe this is the place where IDEA ignores files from version control.